# Titanium: Image view flips after animation to the center of the screen

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I am having some serious issues with the flip animation and am not able to point it out, I have two image view on one view i have two buttons while the other just has an image.

My issue is when i flip from image view to the second image view with the buttons, the button zoom to the center of the screen and then move down to their original place.

From past 3 days i am not able to locate any kind of help online hence finally i decided to post a question here, please help me out given below is the code for those buttons and my animations.

The buttons are actually an image view

```
var cardView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image : imageBackground,
        opacity:1,
        zIndex: 10          
    });

      var cardBackView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
        image :cardImage,
        opacity: 0.1,
        zIndex: 20
    });

// am then adding few image in cardView and assigning images to them as above

var doneImageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
        image: './images/Done.png',
        bottom: screenHeight*0.001,//1,
        right:  screenWidth * 0.0156,//10,
        width: screenWidth * 0.223,//143,
        height:screenHeight*0.0469, //45,
        zIndex: 105

    });

var revokeImageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({ 
        image: './images/Revoke.png',
        bottom: screenHeight*0.001,//1,
        right:  screenWidth * 0.0156,//10,
        width: screenWidth * 0.223,//143,
        height:screenHeight*0.0469, //45,
        zIndex: 105
    });


// creating a container view to hold the cardView and cardBackView
var testView = Titanium.UI.createView();

// assigning click event to both the images


    cardBackView.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      testView.animate({
      view:cardView,    // doneImageView zooms on this animation
      transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT,
     duration:2500
   });
    });

cardView.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  testView.animate({
      view:cardBackView,
    transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT,
    duration:2500
   });
});

// once done i have a container view where i am adding these images

// adding buttons image to the card view
   cardView.add( doneImageView );
   cardView.add( revokeImageView );

// adding the card view and card back view to the container view
  testView.add(cardBackView);
    testView.add(cardView);

// adding the container view to the main window

cardWindow.add(testWindow);
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: What animation do you wanna perform exactly?

Comment: Have you tried to give the imageViews specific location in the container (left;top;width;height)?

Comment: @Spire: I have updated my code please check, i am still facing the issue

Comment: @KirthikaVijayakumar : It;s a basic flip transition from left to right which i am trying to achieve. I have updated my code let me know if you require more details.